# Character Encoding not resolved

Tags: character-encoding, arabic

I have a text file with unknown character formatting, below is a snapshot

```
\216\175\217\133\217\136\216\185 \216\167\217\132\217\133\216\177\216\163\216\169 \216\163\217\130\217\136\217\137 \217\134\217\129\217\136\216\176\216\167\217\139 \217\133\217\134 \216\167\217\132\217\130\217\136\216\167\217\134\217\138\217\134
```

Anyone has an idea how can I convert it to normal text?

Comment: Actually, the pattern looks like a 16-bit encoding. Do you have any idea which language the text might be in?

Comment: Yes, this content should be in Arabic language.

Comment: i have an udpate here, when I print above encoded format inside the Lua parser, I got the correct text which is in arabic,

Comment: Is there any method to decompile or re-convert above text to the normal format.

Comment: by the way, lua is a scripting language used on some platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently how Lua stores strings.  Each `\nnn` represents a single byte where *nnn* is the byte's value in decimal. (A similar notation is commonly used for octal, which threw me off for longer than I would like to admit. I should have noticed that there were digits 8 and 9 in the data!)  This particular string is just plain old UTF-8.

```
$ perl -ple 's/\\(\d{3})/chr($1)/ge' <<<'\216\175\217\133\217\136\216\185 \216\167\217\132\217\133\216\177\216\163\216\169 \216\163\217\130\217\136\217\137 \217\134\217\129\217\136\216\176\216\167\217\139 \217\133\217\134 \216\167\217\132\217\130\217\136\216\167\217\134\217\138\217\134'
دموع المرأة أقوى نفوذاً من القوانين
```

You would obviously get a similar result simply by printing the string from Lua, though I'm not familiar enough with the language to tell you how exactly to do that.

---

Post scriptum: I had to look this up for other reasons, so here's how to execute Lua from the command line.

```
lua -e 'print("\216\175\217\133\217\136\216\185 \216\167\217\132\217\133\216\177\216\163\216\169 \216\163\217\130\217\136\217\137 \217\134\217\129\217\136\216\176\216\167\217\139 \217\133\217\134 \216\167\217\132\217\130\217\136\216\167\217\134\217\138\217\134")'
```

Comment: Google translation: *"Women's tears are the most powerful of laws"*